# Object is possibly 'null' when using ternary operator

Tags: typescript

I have the following in Typescript 4 and using Strict Mode:

```
let userId = parameters.has('userId') ? +parameters.get('userId') : undefined;
```

I get the compilation error `Object is possibly 'null'.` on the part:

```
+parameters.get('userId')
```

The method `parameters.get` returns `string | null` ...

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Could you please share the type of `parameters`?

Comment: Sure, it is an Angular interface: https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of options to solve this, I'll start with what's **not recommended** and it is to use TypeScript's `!` operator, also known as *non-null assertion*

```js
const userId = parameters.has('userId') ? +!parameters.get('userId') : undefined;
```

This way you are telling TypeScript's compiler: "I know better the type and I guarantee it is not `null`". It is not recommended to use it because the value can potentially be `null` under certain conditions.

The second approach is to separate into two steps, first extract the parameter and then check if it defined, the only drawback is that empty string `''` will be converted to `undefined`

```js
const userIdParam = parameters.get('userId');
const userIdOptionOne = userIdParam ? +userIdParam : undefined;
```

You can play with both of these examples [in this TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5&ssl=13&ssc=64&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWzsCCDOUC8UDeAUFFANYQiYBcUmwCAlgHYDmA2gLrFQAWcmACiYoINOo1YBKGgCMA9nIA2EOE24sIwISLH1mLabT2soAHyhMArosXrNAQRvbkooxIO73nQgF9ChABMIAGNFRGhguSY6KDBEEXQsGngkVETMAG5-QgB6HKgAeTBgBiioAEYxCDikEpNmYDkoYAB3JrpqzEJI6OAoS0wMAEkAlJRcWPiXdIA6DS0AcgHhgIXJLJ6Y5YQRopKogqZoPG2RseQoAH4oAGpT0amoGksmIIAzZggArNz8osYygAmGgAVUGFiiAForDYoPxBgh9kwoHJILVSmpNn17nsMQAVNoTGoJDCYGZ8QRLBEjNZXW4AQmJ01Jc00AipK1pz1eEA+R2+QA)

Comment: ! should be at the end. Otherwise it is not operator

Comment: If `parameters.get('userId')` returns `"0"`, your second approach returns `undefined` and not `0`.  [There are problems here](https://tsplay.dev/w186lW)

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for pointing it out, I fixed it by wrapping it with `Number.isNaN`

Comment: Noooo now it will return `true | undefined`.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, got confused, I think it's better to separate to 2 steps instead of using oneliner here